# Sequence not reset when truncating a table

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

After adding primary key in my table, i truncate my table having 14 records. Now, when i am insert again, it is starting from 15. I want to start again by 1. Please tell me how?

Table definition:

```
SQL> create table first(id number(5),name varchar(5));

SQL> alter table first add(constraint first_pk primary key(id)); 

SQL> create sequence first_seq start with 1; 

SQL> create or replace trigger first_trg 
before insert on first for each row 
begin 
select first_seq.nextval into:new.id from dual; 
end; 
/ 

SQL> insert into first values(1,'mini');
```

Comment: You can do this (as per the answer) but you don't need to.  The use of the sequence is to provide a unique numeric identifier to a non-intelligent key.  As such, there is no technical need to reset this value as you will continue to get unique values.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset your sequence. You could simply recreate the sequence, but if you wish to do it manually then here is of the methods to reset the sequence.

For the sake of a example, I have created a sequence called `my_seq`.

First, select the current value from the sequence.

```
SQL> select my_seq.currval from dual;

   CURRVAL
----------
         4
```

In order to reset it, I am going to increment it by -4 which will make it return 0.

```
SQL> alter sequence my_seq increment by -4;

Sequence altered.

SQL> select my_seq.currval from dual;

   CURRVAL
----------
         4

SQL> select my_seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         0
```

Now, alter the sequence to increment by 1.

```
SQL> alter sequence my_seq increment by 1;

Sequence altered.

SQL> select my_seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         1
```

Comment: what would happen by altering the sequence?